# Rename a file in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I created a file from a SQL source to file (in File Share) with aaa.txt filename. After a file is created, I copied it to SFTP as aaa.txt. Then I need to rename the aaa.txt in File Share as aaa_ddMMyyyyhhmmss.txt. Currently, how i do this is:

1. Copy activity from SQL Source to file share as aaa.txt
2. Copy activity from file share to SFTP (same aaa.txt)
3. Copy activity - from aaa.txt to aaa_ddMMyyyyhhmmss.txt <--- just to achieve the renaming.
4. Delete activity to delete aaa.txt in File Share.

I wonder if there's a better way to do Step 3 and 4 because if the file is big then it would be wasted re-creating a file just to have a new filename.

Regards,
Kaye

Answer (score 1):

You can first do Copy activity from SQL Source to SFTP. And then do Copy activity from SFTP to File share and rename your file name in it. So there is no need to do step3 and step4.

Answer (score 0):

it's a good idea, but copying from a SQL query to SFTP gets a timeout issue. it's more time consuming to create the file on the fly and deposit to SFTP than preparing the file in file share first and make a copy to send to SFTP.